# Do we have the Extent Indicator/Map Overviews option in ArcGIS Online New Map Viewer?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-online-webmap

Do we have an extent indicator/map overviews option in New Map Viewer Classic?

The below screenshot is of the Classic Map Viewer.

The end goal is to have this functionality/widget in an experience builder application. Similar to an Overview Widget in Web App builder.

[image]